# Issues detecting data input error in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe **lexdata** and I want to check and count the number of null values and also detect invalid values in the '**sales column**' some of the columns

sample data

```
     city   year    month   sales   
 0  Abilene  2000   1       72.0    
 1  Abilene  2000   2       ola-k   
 2  Abilene  2000   3       130.0   
 3  Abilene  2000   4       lee 
 4  Abilene  2000   5       141.0
```

I successfully checked and counted the null values with the following code:

```
lexdata.isnull().sum()
```

The challenge is to check for invalid values **(string)** in the **sale column**

Comment: And what is the criteria for the value to be invalid? Also add the data sample such that it includes both valid and invalid value

Comment: I have edited the sample data by including some string values

Comment: invalid is string ?

Comment: You can use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` and count the `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric) and pass `coerce` to `errors` parameter, it will try to convert the values to numeric, and if it can not be converted to the numeric, it will return `NaN`, and finally you can count the `null` values after conversion

```py
pd.to_numeric(df['sales'], errors='coerce').isnull().sum()

#output: 2
```